# Setting up (Remote) CLion IDE for C++ BAZEL project with protobufs & external libraries in a heavy git rep

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, bazel, clion, bazel-cpp

I am new to C++ development and currently working in a company where both Python and C++ are used extensively, with a large git repository. I'm facing difficulties in correctly setting up the (Remote) CLion IDE for a C++ BAZEL project that involves protobufs and external libraries.

Due to the size of the repository (Around 10 GB), using SSHFS for local development is not feasible as it is extremely slow (Is there any solution for this?) . Therefore, I am using the remote development feature in CLion, which is still in beta and seems to have some bugs. I have installed the "Bazel for CLion" plugin, but when attempting to sync Bazel with Blaze, I encounter the following error: "xcode_locator should not be invoked on non-darwin systems." It's important to note that the remote IDE is running on Linux, whereas my local machine runs MacOS.

As a newcomer to this setup, I'm unsure if the plugin is expected to configure automatically after installation or if there are additional steps I need to take. I have searched extensively on Google, but there seems to be limited information available on using CLion with Bazel.

As a temporary workaround, I uninstalled the Bazel plugin for CLion and created a fake CMakeLists.txt file using the bazel-cmakelists tool in the repository (https://github.com/lizan/bazel-cmakelists). CLion successfully detects most of the headers; however, it fails to include all the generated compiled protobuf files (.pb.h) and some other external libraries that are supposed to be installed with the Bazel build file.

I would greatly appreciate any guidance or assistance in resolving this issue. If anyone has experience setting up (Remote) CLion with Bazel, protobufs, and external libraries within a heavy git repository, your insights would be invaluable.

Thank you in advance for your help.

- Trying local development with SSHFS (Was too slow)
- Using Remote CLion IDE with "Bazel for CLion" plugin
- Searching in Google for any alternative solutions

Comment: I'm in the same boat as you, see the [issue I posted on the intellij repository](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/4971). There's an existing issue, but no mention of `xcode` in the logs, but I suspect it's the same problem. [They managed to resolve by downgrading](https://github.com/bazelbuild/intellij/issues/4965) to `2023.05.16.0.1-api-version-231`. I just did the exact same, and success :) `Sync finished`. You can find the version download [here](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9554-bazel-for-clion/versions/stable).

Comment: Great to know that you are in the same boat! Thanks a lot for the issue link, it seems like the fix has been merged and soon will be in the new version. I will definitely try the downgraded solution!

How's your bazel experience with CLion? Do you have any tips on how to  configure!?